# Cannot zoom in in PyCharm Jupyter notebook preview

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I am using PyCharm to work on an ipynb file. I am using the ["Split view"-mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html#editor) so that i can see my code and the output next to each other. While using the preview window on the right, I noticed that i am unable to zoom in. No matter in which direction i am moving the mouse wheel, the preview page is always zooming out. When i restart PyCharm the standard zoom-level gets restored.

- Ctrl, - and variations of it didn't work.
- I tried configuring the settings option "Change font size with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel" but this only affects the zooming in the code editor. I did not find any other helpful setting.

I wondered if other people also have this problem/bug or if i am just missing something here.

Comment: I've also hit the problem. It seems like an open bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-44595